# C# HTML-Encode Decode for Malayalam Languages

Tags: c#, html, html-encode

I am trying to Encode/decode Arabic, Malayalam and Bengali characters. I achieved it for Arabic Characters using `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(row["Context"].ToString());` but I cannot do the same for Malayalam and Bengali Languages. 
 I am missing something?
I tried to google it off but still hanging around.

Comment: which is your encoding format?

Comment: @utility There is no format as such. Users are entering the Message Content (which needs to be sent as a SMS) in textbox on a webpage. I need to save that in Database and then read that as SMS text and send them through.

for instance: 'Label1.Text = HTMLEncodeSpecialChars("പ്രിയപെട  ഉപബോക്താവേ , നിങ്ങള്ക്  ഇഷ്ടപെട്ട  ഗാനം  കണ്ടെത്തുവാൻ )'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution using a function I got after searching on Google. I commented the if part and this does the trick for me.

```
 Public Shared Function HTMLEncodeSpecialChars(text As String) As String
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    If text IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each c As Char In text
            sb.Append([String].Format("&#{0};", AscW(c)))

            'If Not [Char].IsLetterOrDigit(c) Then
            '    ' special chars
            '    sb.Append([String].Format("&#{0};", AscW(c)))
            'Else
            '    sb.Append(c)
            'End If
        Next
    End If
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Thanks for the helping me the get a solution on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `UTF-8` encoding :

```
byte[] encodedDataAsBytes =
System.Convert.FromBase64String(m_enc);
string returnValue =
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);
return returnValue;
```

More [reference](http://gnidesign.blogspot.in/2011/04/c-how-to-encode-or-decode-string-to.html)

Comment: I cannot go with UTF encoding as the other languages are using HTML Encoding and I need to maintain the consistency.